# Regex to catch comma-separated decimal numbers not inside latex command

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex to catch comma-separated decimal numbers not inside LaTeX command `\num{}`.

Here are examples of what I want to catch:

```
2,47
12,67
\mathbf{12,76}
```

Here are examples that I don't want to catch:

```
\num{2,76}
\num{12,76}
```

I tried this regex but it doesn't work.

```
(?<!num\{)(\d*\,\d*)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could perpend a word boundary `\b(?<!num\{)\d+\,\d+`

Comment: Thanks, @Thefourthbird. Is it possible to adapt your command to exclude multiple commands? Say `\num{}` and `\SI{}`.

Comment: Would the following work [`^(?!\\(?:num|SI){)[^\d\n]*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/hvWQaR/7)

Comment: @Marca85 Can you add the tool or language that you are using?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am using the Find/Replace tool in Atom. Thanks.

Comment: To remove numbers outside the tags, use `(\\\w+\{[^{}]*\})|\d*,?\d+` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. Thanks. Actually, I would like to place inside a `\num{}` or `\SI{}` tag when it is not already inside one. So I would like to find all occurrences that are not in these tags.

Comment: You could list multiple lookbehinds `\b(?<!num\{)(?<!SI\{)\d+\,\d+` What do you want to do with the matches? Can there be multiple matches, and if so do you want to match all of them in 1 match or separate matches?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Great. This works for me. I can not go through each match and treat accordingly. Thanks for your help everyone :).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(?<!\\num\{(?=\d+,\d+}))(?<!\\SI\{(?=\d+,\d+}))\b\d+,\d+`? See https://regex101.com/r/MVU3tj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prepend the pattern with a word boundary and if you want to exclude multiple patterns, you could add another lookbehind.

Note that you don't have to escapte the `{` and the `,` and using `\d*` matches 0 or more digits.

```
\b(?<!num{)(?<!SI{)\d+,\d+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/efQxWc/1)

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanations!